# Where did the Bnei Israel go to the Mikveh in the desert?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, mikvah-ritual-bath, kabbalat-hatorah, har-sinai

Our Sages in Yevamot 46b and Keritot 9a in the Bavli say that the requirements for a proper conversion are bringing a sacrifice, Mila, Kabalat Hatorah and immersing in a Mikvah.

The Gemara in Yevamot 46b understands that Bnei Israel converted at Maamad Har Sinai: sacrifices were brought (Shemot 24:5), Mila was performed in Egypt before leaving in order to perform Korban Pesach (Kol Bo comment on Yechezkel 16:7 from the Pesach Haggadah), Kabalat Hatorah at Matan Torah, but what about immersing in the Mikvah?

When, where and how did this happen? How about the Jewish ladies after Matan Torah immersing after being Niddah? And the other mitsvot that require immersion?

Comment: Do you mean which particular spring did they dip in? Probably whichever was close by. I'm not sure what else you're expecting

Comment: Related was-beer-mityam-kosher-as-a-mikve https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106885/was-beer-mityam-kosher-as-a-mikve

Comment: If the Torah doesn't mention it, why do we need to think it happened?

Answer (score 2):

[Chabad.org says in [The Mikvah](https://www.chabad.org/theJewishWoman/article_cdo/aid/1541/jewish/The-Mikvah.htm)

> The world’s natural bodies of water—its oceans, rivers, wells and
>   spring-fed lakes—are mikvahs in their most primal form. They contain
>   waters of Divine source, and thus, tradition teaches, the power to
>   purify.

This status implies that the Well of Miriam would have served. Indeed the same article states explicitly:

> In the desert, the famed “well of Miriam” served as a mikvah. And
>   Aaron and his sons’ induction into the priesthood was marked by
>   immersion in the mikvah.

[Miriam's Well](https://shiratdevorah.blogspot.com/2011/06/miriams-well.html) says

> In addition to providing water to drink, Miriam's well also made it
>   possible for the mitzvah of taharas hamishpachah [family purity] to be
>   fulfilled.  There was no other source of water in the desert, so
>   Miriam's well served as a mikvah, enabling children to be born
>   throughout the forty years.

citing as a source:

> Source: Gutnick Chumash: Based on various Sichos of the Lubavitcher Rebbe

Comment: What is the source of this idea please?

Comment: @Eli83 The only source I could find was the Gutnik Chumash which apparently references the Lubavitcher Rebbe. I do not have a copy of this. If I find a further source for this, I will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure the Yalkut Meam Loez brings this question and as I recall there were two answers. 1. The Well of Miriam and 2. when the Yidden passed through the Yam Suf there was small period when they first got wet and it counted as tevilah for Gerus before Matan TOrah.I only remember it was at the end of Parsha but I don't remember which one. I will try to find and post.
Just imagine 600,ooo Jews toveling in Miriams well 3 days before Matan Torah. It must have formed a large river deep enough to qualify as a mikveh, so it was more than just  a spring.