# Is synthetically generated water Kosher for Mikve?

Tags: halacha-theory, mikvah-ritual-bath

Following "[was-beer-miryam-kosher-as-a-mikve](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106885/was-beer-miryam-kosher-as-a-mikve)",

Water [can be generated](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20make%20water%20from%20hydrogen%20and%20oxygen&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIL857IL857&oq=how%20to%20make%20water%20from%20hydro&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.7279j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) synthetically from hydrogen and oxygen (don't try it at home!).

Is this water Kosher for Mikve dip?

Comment: It would have to be produced in-situ to avoid becoming "drawn water", wouldn't it? (Assuming it could be deemed kosher to begin with)

Comment: @JoshK As you probably already understood I focus on the essence of the water, not the procedure.

Comment: Vote to reopen- the din of man-made water molecules is not necessarily that of ice or steam