# While Bnei Yisrael Lived in the Desert for 40 Years How did they manage to keep ritual purity?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, dor-hamidbar

When Bnei Yisrael roamed the desert for 40 years where did they get water to bathe? to ritually purify themselves before relations. ie; the women.
did they bathe in the salt water?

Comment: Very similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106881

Comment: I think i saw they used biar miryam as mikveh.